# engine push rods

Tags: engine, toyota, valve-guide, push-rod

I have a Toyota owner Jeep.  Had a blown head gasket, most likely cause it got over heated.  I removed the head and had machine shop do a valve job and had the head re-surfaced, put together, set the valves to the spec's called for, no problem till I started the motor.

It made some load clacking noise, so turned it off.  I checked the rockers. I found a bent push rod in number 4 cylinder.  I took the head off again, back to the machine shop and they found a broken valve guide and also put in a new exhaust valve.

Back home, another new gasket set, set the valve adjustments again. All is ok till I started the engine again, then, clack noise was back again, turned it off.

This time it was the push rod in # 3 cylinder bent.  So I have to wait till the 5th of april to get it tore down again.

I think its going to be another broken valve guide and will also need a new exhaust valve.

***What could could be the problem?***

I'm afraid to do this again.

Comment: Did you turn it over by hand a few times before starting it?

Comment: Sounds like screwed up timing to me.

Comment: This question should _really_ be edited to make it readable.  Please try to format questions more like something you would send to your boss - pay attention to punctuation, sentences, and paragraphs.

Comment: I did edit "tube" to read "rod" ... those are push rods you are talking about.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 now it makes a whole lot more sense :)

Comment: @mike004006 - I'm wondering if you aren't installing the rocker arms correctly. If you are adjusting them too tight, it might be causing this issue, especially if the valve is contacting the piston face in the process. Knowing what year and engine is in your Toyota would help as well, so we can understand exactly how to help you get this diagnosed.

Comment: Sounds like a 70's FJ40.  Jeep.  Pushrods.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  Yeah, adjusting the valve right into the piston, maybe?

Comment: Can you provide the make/model/year of the vehicle?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there could only be two main causes here:

1. Engine timing, I would say that it is the most likely cause, have you used the factory timing marks? Always turn the engine over by hand at least twice. The cam could be a complete turn out.
2. Valve clearance is way to tight, I find this unlikely because something would have to be going majorly wrong to adjust the valves to tight that something bends.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you put the intake pushrod on the exhaust side vice versa. If they are different sizes make sure they are on the right side.